# How to change the amplitude of pulsetrain of rectangular pulses in Matlab

Tags: matlab, amplitude

I am plotting a pulsetrain of rectangular pulses.

```
pulse_periods = [0:128]*period; %128 pps 
%works for Ampl. default  = 1, 
r1 = pulstran(t,pulse_periods,'rectpuls', w);
```

This gives a default amplitude of 1 for the rectangular pulses.

I need to change it to 0.5

I tried

```
    pulse_periods = [[0:128]*period;0.5 * [0:128]]' %128 pps 
    %does not work for Ampl. = 0.5, 
    r1 = pulstran(t,pulse_periods,'rectpuls', w);
```

This is a modification of the periodic gaussian pulse example given in Matlab
https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/pulstran.html?searchHighlight=pulstran

I am unable to change the amplitude for the required rectangular pulses .

What is the mistake I am doing ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included code to define `t` and `w`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second column of `pulse_periods` should be the amplitude of each pulse. In the example from the documentation, they wanted the pulse amplitude to change. If you want the pulse amplitude to stay at a constant 0.5, then you should do instead:

```
pulse_periods = [(0:128)*period; 0.5 * ones(1,129)]';
```

As part of a minimum working example:

```
period = 1/128;
pulse_periods = [(0:128)*period; 0.5 * ones(1,129)]';
w = period * 0.5;
t = linspace(0, 1, 2e3)';
r1 = pulstran(t,pulse_periods,'rectpuls', w);
plot(t,r1);
```

Note that you could have also simply scaled the output from your "default amplitude of 1" case (i.e. `r1 = r1 * 0.5`);